# Doesn't get the value of item array from mentioned Json in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: android, json, xamarin

I am not getting the value of Item array from response array when I am trying this code but its not working.

**This is my Json**

```
{ "response": [ { "id": "8", "item_cat_name": "Pizza", "item": [ { "item_id": "1", "item_name": "Veg Singles", "item_rate": "170", "item_image": "uploads\/20160726125847images (1).jpg" }, { "item_id": "2", "item_name": "Cheese & Tomato", "item_rate": "255", "item_image": "uploads\/20160726125948images.jpg" }, { "item_id": "13", "item_name": "Paneer", "item_rate": "0", "item_image": "uploads\/images.jpg" } ] }, { "id": "10", "item_cat_name": "Burger", "item": [ { "item_id": "11", "item_name": "Cheez Burger", "item_rate": "0", "item_image": "" }, { "item_id": "19", "item_name": "abc", "item_rate": "0", "item_image": "uploads\/images.jpg" }, { "item_id": "21", "item_name": "Chicken Burger", "item_rate": "0", "item_image": "uploads\/20160726131419images (1).jpg" } ] }, { "id": "11", "item_cat_name": "Cake", "item": [ { "item_id": "14", "item_name": "Choclate", "item_rate": "0", "item_image": "20160726124105" } ] }, { "id": "12", "item_cat_name": "Ice Cream", "item": null }, { "id": "13", "item_cat_name": "Sandwich", "item": null }, { "id": "14", "item_cat_name": "Hard Drink", "item": null }, { "id": "15", "item_cat_name": "abc", "item": null } ] }
```

**Here is my Code**

```
 JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(result);
 JArray response = (JArray)jobject["response"];
 foreach (var ItemCategory in response){
    ItemCategory item_category = new ItemCategory();
    item_category.id = ItemCategory["id"].ToString();
    item_category.item_cat_name = ItemCategory["item_cat_name"].ToString();

    JArray jArrayItem = (JArray)ItemCategory["item"].ToString(); //Error in this line

    lstItemCategory.Add(item_category);
  }
```

**Item Category Class**

```
public class ItemCategory {
                public string id { get; set; }
                public string item_cat_name { get; set; }
                public List<Item> item { get; set; }
     }
```

**Item Class**

```
public class Item
        {
           public string item_id;
           public string item_name;
           public string item_rate;
        }
```

Comment: You can create your POJO classes from here easily http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @burhanuddin-rashid that is a great resource !! thanks for sharing

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Thanks but right now I am writing code in Xamarin android

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) ?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I am using this but nothing would be show in toast var jsonItemCate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemCategory>(result);
Toast.MakeText(this,"Response:- " + jsonItemCate.item_cat_name, ToastLength.Long).Show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://json2csharp.com/ you can paste your json and generate the classes for the object in question.

After that I suggest you to use [Json.Net NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) that will deserialize the full object without the using of specifics casts and indexing like your doing in the answer.

I was able to fully deserialize the object.

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string item_id { get; set; }
        public string item_name { get; set; }
        public string item_rate { get; set; }
        public string item_image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string item_cat_name { get; set; }
        public List<Item> item { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Response> response { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var json = "{ \"response\": [ { \"id\": \"8\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Pizza\", \"item\": [ { \"item_id\": \"1\", \"item_name\": \"Veg Singles\", \"item_rate\": \"170\", \"item_image\": \"uploads\\/20160726125847images (1).jpg\" }, { \"item_id\": \"2\", \"item_name\": \"Cheese & Tomato\", \"item_rate\": \"255\", \"item_image\": \"uploads\\/20160726125948images.jpg\" }, { \"item_id\": \"13\", \"item_name\": \"Paneer\", \"item_rate\": \"0\", \"item_image\": \"uploads\\/images.jpg\" } ] }, { \"id\": \"10\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Burger\", \"item\": [ { \"item_id\": \"11\", \"item_name\": \"Cheez Burger\", \"item_rate\": \"0\", \"item_image\": \"\" }, { \"item_id\": \"19\", \"item_name\": \"abc\", \"item_rate\": \"0\", \"item_image\": \"uploads\\/images.jpg\" }, { \"item_id\": \"21\", \"item_name\": \"Chicken Burger\", \"item_rate\": \"0\", \"item_image\": \"uploads\\/20160726131419images (1).jpg\" } ] }, { \"id\": \"11\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Cake\", \"item\": [ { \"item_id\": \"14\", \"item_name\": \"Choclate\", \"item_rate\": \"0\", \"item_image\": \"20160726124105\" } ] }, { \"id\": \"12\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Ice Cream\", \"item\": null }, { \"id\": \"13\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Sandwich\", \"item\": null }, { \"id\": \"14\", \"item_cat_name\": \"Hard Drink\", \"item\": null }, { \"id\": \"15\", \"item_cat_name\": \"abc\", \"item\": null } ] }\n";

        var finalObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Please @JagjeetSingh mark my answer as correct. Thank you.